# Date filtering to extract from view not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I HAVE A CODE THAT CONVERT A DATE FORMAT TO DD/MM/YYYY to create a view INITIALLY THE DATE FORMAT was dd.mm.yyyy hh24.mi.ss . so I converted it.

```
  NVL(TO_CHAR(D_TRANS.TRANS_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'NULL') AS CASE_DATE
```

I want to get data from the view using the Between date filter, initially was working and now is no longer working. It is coming with this error

"a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
           incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
           required by the format model.
*Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
           elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.

```
     SELECT * FROM VIEW_info   
  WHERE CASE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('&ENTER_START_DATE', 'DD/MM/YYYY')  
     AND TO_DATE('&ENTER_END_DATE',  'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

I tried this as well but is giving only extracting 5 info from thodsands of records

```
 SELECT * FROM VIEW_info
 WHERE CASE_DATE BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('&ENTER_START_DATE', 
'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')  AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('&ENTER_END_DATE',  
'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: Include both the converted date and the original date in your view and then write the `BETWEEN` condition using the original date

Comment: Why do you want your view to show a string version of the date - why not just return the date and let the query against the view format it as a string if that is needed?

Comment: INITIALLY THE DATE FORMAT was dd.mm.yyyy hh24.mi.ss .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That just can't work; stings are sorted differently from dates (or numbers), so '11' comes before '2'.

Your best option is to work with dates, if `CASE_DATE` *is* a date. Is it? Then you'd

```
select * from view_info
where case_date between to_date('&start_date', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
                    and to_date('&end_date'  , 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

If it is a string (`VARCHAR2` column), then you'll have to convert it to date first (presuming that format is `dd/mm/yyyy`), e.g.

```
select * from view_info
where to_date(case_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') between to_date('&start_date', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
                                           and to_date('&end_date'  , 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

As you can never know what users enter as strings, `CASE_DATE` might easily be '09/04/2019' or 'dd/fx/234v' or '$$75x#f9' and you won't be able to `TO_DATE` such values, and your query will fail.

Comment: I have tried this before, it is given the same error. It is not about validating now, just to enter correct date format and it should extract it

Comment: i made a mistake by putting NULL in the format as well if empty so the Date is trying to convert NULL, the end user is asking for NULL to replaceempty field. Now that I remove it, it is working. Your code is the same as mine which is the first code and I accepted it as answer

Comment: OK; I'm glad you made it work. Thank you for letting us know.

Answer (score 0):

First you convert `DATE` to `CHAR`:

```
TO_CHAR(D_TRANS.TRANS_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS CASE_DATE
```

Then you convert a string value to date:

```
TO_DATE('&ENTER_START_DATE', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

and comparing `CHAR` and `DATE` datatypes.
That's the cause of your error.

If you are working with dates, why do you convert it to `CHAR` in the first place?
If you still need an additional `CHAR` column, just add it to the view, do not replace the existing one.

Comment: The date format from the database  was dd.mm.yyyy hh24.mi.ss . I need to convert it to that format needed.

Comment: There's no format for a date. It's up to you to decide how to represent (or print) a date value. Convert it to CHAR only when you have to show it to the end user, but do all calculations on the DATE type.

Comment: I am showing it to end user, that is their requirement.